# How to access stdClass object value's key

Tags: php, loops, foreach, key, stdclass

is there a way to access a key of a value in stdClass object without having two foreach loops?

instead of:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $object) {
    foreach ($object as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . $value;
    }
}
```

something like:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $object) {
    echo $object->username->key;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the two foreach loops? You want to go through each of your array elements and for each element you want to go through all properties.

Comment: I just want to make the code shorter.

Comment: You can't walk 10 meters with just 5. So you also can't loop through all of your data with less iterations.